# Spring Cloud 1.4.2 Edgware.SR2 config decryption is not happening on client side

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, public-key-encryption, spring-cloud-config

I used [this project from spring.io](https://spring.io/guides/gs/centralized-configuration/) and added asymmetric encryption and decryption by having below property files.

```
<code>
    application properties (server side) :
       server.port=8888
       spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=https://{uname}:{password}@{giturl}
       encrypt.key-store.location=classpath:/server.jks
       encrypt.key-store.password=letmein
       encrypt.key-store.alias=mytestkey
       encrypt.key-store.secret=changeme
       spring.cloud.config.server.encrypt.enabled=false
       security.user.name=root
       security.user.password=s3cr3t
</code>
<code>
    bootstrap.properties (client side) :
       spring.application.name=config-client
       spring.cloud.config.uri=http://root:s3cr3t@localhost:8888
       encrypt.key-store.location=classpath:/server.jks
       encrypt.key-store.password=letmein
       encrypt.key-store.alias=mytestkey
       encrypt.key-store.secret=changeme
       server.port=8089    
</code>
```

The property file within my git has

```
<code>
    message={cipher}{key:mytestkey}AQA5...    
</code>
```

Unfortunately, I am getting encrypted message in my `RestController` class which is in a Spring Boot application.

```
<code>
     @RefreshScope
       @RestController
       class MessageRestController {
          @Value("${message}")
          private String message;

          @RequestMapping("/message")
          String getMessage() {
              return this.message;
          }
       }    
</code>
```

Have I missed something to decrypt it?

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: Am using spring cloud config 1.4.2.RELEASE

Comment: <version>Edgware.SR2</version>

Comment: you might need to use `keyStore` (case sensitive).

Comment: (From Review:) I improved the title and the code formatting of your post. Please check if it's alright.

Comment: I tried with Brixton.SR7 version and it works fine. Somehow Edgware.SR2 is causing issue.